# Besides vs. After

Tags: word-meaning

Are these two sentences the same meaning?

> 1. Besides going to the gym on weekdays, he plays football on Saturdays.
> 2. After going to the gym on weekdays, he plays football on Saturdays.

If there are some gap of meaning, tell me the differences.

Comment: Could you explain a bit about where your confusion lies? Also, "weekdays" (plural) vs. "Saturday" (singular) could confuse the meaning, since you are joining the two phrases. Maybe "Saturdays"?

Comment: Sorry you confuse.you're right.and I want to ask another question.which is close to the meaning of this sentence , " He goes to the gym on weekends and plays football on Saturdays." ?

Comment: I wouldn't use *after* since your are describing repetitive activities. You would have to be following strict calendar "Sunday thru Saturday" thinking. Because going to the gym will still occur after playing football.

Comment: The more natural use of "after" tends to be immediately after. For example: "After going to the gym he takes a shower and goes home to study."

Comment: Thank you for giving answers , User and Leo! I understand the nuance of  the "after".I also have the same feeling as user3169, after is not used for repetitive activities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sentences may have the same meaning

> Habitually during the week he goes to the gym and on Saturdays he plays football

the reason is that weekdays and Saturdays are mutually exclusive.

If you took out "on Saturdays"

> Besides going to the gym on weekdays, he plays football.
>   After going to the gym on weekdays, he plays football.

the sentences might have two different meanings since one specifies *when* he plays football, "after", but the other only specifies *that* he plays football, "besides".

Comment: I would not say they have the same meaning at all.  *Besides* just means that he does both things.  *After* specifically locates the gym-going and football-playing in relation to each other.

Comment: @stangdon Usually, I would agree with you, however the OP has used a special case in the wording of the sentence. The reason they are the same is because one action, "going to the gym" only happens during the week, where as "playing football" only happens on Saturdays, they are mutually exclusive in terms of days of the week.  As mentioned in the answer, if "on Saturdays" is removed, a time relationship could be understood.  Neither sentence mentions the frequency of playing football on Saturdays, both sentences could mean the every week (7 days) he goes to the gym and plays football.

Comment: I agree with you that in practice, they essentially mean the same thing - going to the gym during the week, and playing football on Saturdays - and for that reason it doesn't really matter which one is used here.   I just wouldn't want the OP to get the idea that *besides* and *after* meant the same thing in general.

Answer (score 0):

Both sentences convey the same facts, but the first adds a slight implication. "Besides" in the first sentence is used as a preposition with the meaning of "In addition to." "After" in the second sentence means "Subsequent to."

Both sentences, therefore, tell us that the subject goes to the gym on weekdays and plays football on Saturday, and the second adds the trivial observation that Saturday comes after the weekdays. The first sentence, though, subtly implies that the subject is very active athletically. The preposition "Besides" here carries with it some of its adverbial meaning of "Moreover," so the sense which some native English readers would take from the first sentence is:

> Not only does he go to the gym on weekdays, he plays football on Saturday.

Comment: I really appreciate you telling me the answer. But can we use "after" in the sentence of the repetitive activity? After means "Subsequence to" so I don't think we can use it in the sentenc.

Comment: If you are asking whether sentence number 2 is grammaticaly correct, Yes, it is.